# how could I access the element of a high-dimensional matrix in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, pointers, opencv, matrix

I am trying to use a 4-d matrix in OpenCV, the initialization part looks like this:

```
int feature_points_size[] = {bincellDim.x , bincellDim.y , bincellDim.z , 100};
feature_points.create(4 , feature_points_size , CV_64F);
```

But the library doesn't allow me to access the elements of feature_points with 'at' like this:

```
feature_points.at<double>(k , j , i , l) = stickfea_code.at<double>(l , 0);
feature_points.at<double>(k , j , i , l + 50) = countfea_code.at<double>(l , 0);
```

it seems Mat.at<> doesn't have a version for 4 inputs
what's the best practice to access the element of it ?

thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv::Mat::at<>` does, in fact have an n-dim overload, you will need to use the [`T& Mat::at(const int* idx)`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#template%3Ctypename%20T%3E%20const%20T&%20Mat::at(const%20int*%20idx)%20const) version.
Alternatively, just write your own (external) wrapper for it that you might use like this:

```
at4D<double>(feature_points,k,j,i,l);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just example following the answer of @Adi-Shavit:

```
std::vector<int> dims = {1, 3, 700, 400};
cv::Mat mat4d = cv::Mat(std::vector<int>, CV_32FC1);
int p[4];
p[0] = 0;
for (unsigned hi=0; hi<dims[3]; hi++) {
    p[3] = hi;
    for (unsigned wi=0; wi<dims[2]; wi++) {
        p[2] = wi;
        for (unsigned ci=0; ci<dims[1]; ci++) {
            p[1] = ci;
            float value = mat4d.at<float>(&p[0]);
            mat4d.at<float>(&p[0]) = some_new_value;
        }
    }
}
```